# Android OnTouchListener

Tags: android, xml, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I want to implement OnTouchListener in my app. What I want:

- when I touch the screen , I need to show or hide some action: here when I touch ImageView , show the LinearLayout which handle actions

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_af"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivaf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llaffbtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_white_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and what i tried in my java class:

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivaf);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_af);
    affBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llaffbtn);
    rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                affBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                affBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: this code not working. when i touch imageView the linearlayout where i put two other buttons doesn't disappear

Comment: If you just want to hide `linearLayout` Why don't you use `onClickListener` ?

Comment: I want to show or hide every time I touch

Answer (score 0):

instead of `View.INVISIBLE` ==> `View.Gone`

**Update**

Try it without `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {...` like :

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivaf);
    rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_af);
    affBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llaffbtn);
    rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            affBtn.setVisibility(affBtn.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

this code working on my devise.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using invisible will still have the object take up space in layout. Using Gone instead will hide the object and remove the space.

```
affBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I want to show or hide every time I touch. If i click and make visibility GONE, when i click again , how to make it visible ?

Comment: Set is to visible when you want to see it again

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't really want an `OnClickListener`?

```
rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        affBtn.setVisibility(affBtn.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

This will make your view toggle between visible and invisible on every click.

If you want the view to disappear along with the space that it takes up, change `View.INVISIBLE` in the code snippet above to `View.GONE`

Answer (score 0):

Try returning "True" after ACTION_DOWN. Android will then listen to ACTION_UP events and call it when it happens. I had a similar issue in an earlier project of mine.

```
rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            affBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            affBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```